# How to disable SQL Server JDBC SSL Encryption (in 10.2 driver version and onwards)

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

Since 10.2, SQL Server enables SSL by default, which is a breaking change by their own admission:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/release-notes-for-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver16#changes-in-102

Now, the question is how to adapt an existing, good/working JDBC connection string to not use encryption. E.g. what should this URL become?

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=SomeDatabase;
```

Comment: someone should add the right tags to this. it took me 20 mins to find the answer in the docs which is the sweet spot for where i think it start being the docs' fault rather than mine for not being organized well enough.

Answer (score 13):

Seems to be just add `encrypt=false;` to the end, and the app starts up again.

Comment: Yes, this would be backed up by [Step 3: Proof of concept connecting to SQL using Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-java) which shows the opposite (normal) case of `encrypt=true;` in the connection string.