# Spark action throws "Cannot execute the query against OLE DB provider "INSQL" for linked server "INSQL" from Wonderware Historian DB

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, wonderware, historian

Using Spark, I have successfully loaded a Dataframe from a Wonderware Historian SQL DB (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76695428/5392289)).

Listing the column names:

```
df.columns
```

> 'TagName',
> 'Value',
> 'vValue',
> 'Quality',
> 'QualityDetail',
> 'OPCQuality',
> 'wwTagKey',
> 'wwRowCount',
> 'wwResolution',
> ...

I however when I execute an Action on the DataFrame an error is thrown:

```
df.select('TagName').head()
```

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
> Task 0 in stage 13.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
> 0.3 in stage 13.0 (TID 55) (10.252.13.132 executor driver): com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: An error occurred
> during the current command (Done status 0). Cannot execute the query
> "SELECT Tbl1001.TagName Col1005 FROM Runtime.dbo.History Tbl1001"
> against OLE DB provider "INSQL" for linked server "INSQL".

Any Action raises the same kind of error.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to add a query:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM History WHERE TagName LIKE '%' AND wwRetrievalMode = 'Full'"

remote_table = (spark.read
  .format("sqlserver")
  .option("host", "mydomainname.com")
  .option("user", "myusername")
  .option("password", "mypassword")
  .option("encrypt", True)
  .option("trustServerCertificate", True)
  .option("query", query)
  .load()
)
```